# Existence of nondecreasing subsequence

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Let $(c_i) 1\le i\le 2^n$ be a sequence of integers that satisfy $0\le c_i\le i-1$. Prove that there exists a nondecreasing subsequence of $c_i$ of size $n$.

This is basically a translation of this year’s IMO P5. I was at the IMO this year and I didn’t do it, my approach was an induction on $n$ which didn’t lead me to anywhere. This translation seems to be a well known problem. Is it? And could there be a solution of this translation different from that of the IMO?

Comment: When you say "translation", is it equivalent? If it is, any solution of the original problem gives you a proof for this. What is the translation?

Comment: Yes, I will write how I got to this tomorrow.

Comment: The question is a weaker version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752434/maximal-non-decreasing-subsequence) question.