# Maximal non-decreasing subsequence

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. A sequence $(y_i)$  with $0\le i\le 2^n-1$ is called beautiful of rank $n$ if for all $0\le i\le 2^n-1$, $0\le y_i\le i$. For a beautiful sequence $(y_i)$ of rank $n$ let $A((y_i))$ be the size of the maximal nondecreasing subsequence of $(y_i)$. Find $min  \ A(y_i)$ over all beautiful sequences of rank $n$.

It can be shown by a straightforward example that this number cannot exceed $n+1$ as is shown in the attached picture which is easily generalizable by induction. We take $y_{2^n-1}=0, y_{2^n-2}=1, \cdots, y_{2^{n-1}}=2^{n-1}-1$, and redoing this.  I think there always should be a non-decreasing subsequence of that size but I couldn't prove it.[image]

Comment: It all looks good now. I will tidy up my comments and then see if I can help you answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel $n + 1$ is the correct answer. We can argue this by induction. The case $n = 1$ is trivial.

Suppose we know the result for all smaller $n' < n$, and suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is a counterexample for $n$. The main claim is that for every $0 \leq i \leq n - 1$, every number $a \in [2^i, 2^{i + 1} - 1]$ must appear in the sequence $A$ for at most $n - i - 1$ times. Otherwise, we can form an non-decreasing subsequence of length $n + 1$ by taking a non-decreasing subsequence of length $i + 1$ in $A[0, 2^{i} - 1]$, followed by all occurrence of $a$.

Summing the number of appearance over all such $a$, we conclude that the number of non-zero terms in the sequence $A$ is at most
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} (n - i - 1) \cdot 2^i = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 2} \sum_{i = 0}^j 2^i = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 2} (2^{j + 1} - 1) = 2^n - n - 1.$$
However, this means that $0$ must appear at least $n + 1$ times, so all occurrence of $0$ forms a non-decreasing subsequence, contradiction.

Comment: thank you, this has been fixed.

Comment: I don’t understand the part after “However, this gives a contradiction, since “

Comment: Sorry those words shouldn't be there. I clarified that part a bit further.

Comment: How did you bound the number on non-zero terms in the sequence? I get that there are at most $n-i-1$ of each $a$ in $[2^i;2^{i+1}-1]$, I can’t see how that implies what you wrote

Comment: Each non-zero term must lie in $[2^i, 2^{i + 1} - 1]$ for some $0 \leq i \leq n - 1$, and the number of terms lying in $[2^i, 2^{i + 1} - 1]$  is at most $2^i(n - i - 1)$.

Comment: Got it! nice solution!! By the way if you’re interested this is a reformulation of IMO 2023 P5 (after some algebraic manipulations). Most inductive arguments for that version fail, so it’s nice to see one that works here.